# What is the point of considering $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{Spec}R}R_p$ injection instead of $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{mSpec}R}R_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is very likely to be a dumb question. I denote $\operatorname{mSpec}R$ as the set of all maximal ideals of $R$.

> What is the point of considering $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{Spec}R}R_p$ injection instead of $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{mSpec}R}R_p$ injection?

Normally I would consider $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{mSpec}R}R_p$ as $R$ is $R$-module by itself and this injectivity implies $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{Spec} R}R_p$ injectivity. This makes me feel the injectivity of $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{Spec}R}R_p$ is too strong or redundant information. (It seems I can construct scheme from this part of the information? Correct me if I am wrong here.) To detect triviality of sheaves/sheaf of modules over $\operatorname{Spec}R$, it suffices to play with $\operatorname{mSpec}R$.

> Probably the former injection $M\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{Spec}R}M_p$ gives a more refined picture of vector bundles over $\operatorname{Spec}R$?

The reason to ask this question is that construction of scheme comes from $\operatorname{Spec}R$ instead of $\operatorname{mSpec}R$. However given injection $R\to\prod_{p\in\operatorname{mSpec}R}R_p$, it seems that one has all necessary information to construct scheme and go back. It seems this should hold similarly for sheaf of modules as well?

Comment: This is not really possible to answer without some indication of the context in which you want to "consider" these maps.

Comment: @EricWofsey Why scheme is constructed from $SpecR$ instead of $mSpecR$. It seems that given localizations at all maximal ideals I will have enough information to reconstruct $R$ from injectivity. Correct me if I am wrong here. If this is the case, shouldn't I consider $mSpecR$ instead of $SpecR$ apriori?

Comment: The spectrum of a ring has far more purposes than merely considering the map $R\to\prod_{p\in Spec R}R_p$.  If your question is actually why the spectrum of a ring is defined using prime ideals instead of maximal ideals, you should say so clearly in your post.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have edited the post a bit. And does this contain enough information to describe the sheaf of modules as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, one major problem with $\operatorname{mSpec}$ is that it is not a functor!  Given a homomorphism $f:A\to B$ of commutative rings, there is typically no induced map $f^*:\operatorname{mSpec} B\to\operatorname{mSpec} A$, since the inverse image of a maximal ideal may not be maximal.  For instance, consider the inclusion map $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$.  What maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ would you send the maximal ideal $0\subset\mathbb{Q}$ to?

Comment: Obligatory mention: $\text{mSpec}$ is a functor when restricted to the category of finitely generated $k$-algebras for a field $k$. If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a morphism between two such objects then $\mathfrak{m}\subset B$ is maximal implies $E:=B/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $k$. So $A/f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$ is a finite $k$-algebra between $k$ and $E$ and hence is a field.

Comment: Of course, I still don't argue that $\text{mSpec}$ is preferable. Generic points are great.